# Is there any special sites to get a rich backgrounds/images for mobile apps?

Tags: android, image, background

Right now i have created one android application.But my application is not so looking as like the formal application. ie.,like the apps available on the play store.

The backgrounds,the button images and the other component's images/backgrounds of my app are looking so simple and like a toy app.

So far i searched for backgrounds and images through Google but i am unsatisfied.

Can any one tell me is there any special sites to get a rich backgrounds/images particularly for mobile apps.

Suggestions please..

Thanks for your precious time!..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if *off the shelf* graphics are the **only** solution to making a richer app. Graphics wise that is.

There is a huge difference in Mobile development vis-a-vis developing for something like, say, a website. Again, graphics wise. At some point of time, regardless of the source or the nature of the resources, you will have to build your own `styles` and `themes` using the said resources and find your own combinations that works not just for you, but primarily, for the **user**.

You being satisfied with what you have found so far is **mighty subjective**. Nonetheless, see if any of the links below help you find what you might like. But, to each his own. There is no accounting for tastes as they say. ;-)

1. http://www.2expertsdesign.com/graphics/50-free-psd-files-for-mobile-design-and-development
2. http://www.medialoot.com/
3. http://naldzgraphics.net/freebies/30-free-mobile-web-application-icons/
4. http://365psd.com/
5. http://dailytekk.com/2012/07/31/200-graphic-app-web-design-tools-resources/
6. http://www.awwwards.com/inspirational-and-useful-resources-for-app-designers.html
7. http://www.psdfreebies.com

BTW, these links are from a simple [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=mobile+app+graphic+resource&oq=mobile+app+graphic+resource&gs_l=hp.3..33i21.90.8785.0.9311.27.26.0.1.1.2.259.4260.0j24j2.26.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.Km1biplJPug&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bmk&fp=1ae9bc3e4ce8fa6d&biw=1440&bih=775)

Answer (score 0):

You can find useful resources provided by Android, such as icons and styles, here:
http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html